# Cannot remove block comment in Eclipse after formatting

Tags: eclipse, formatting

Eclipse's automatic formatter changes block comments such that the Source > Remove Block Comment does not completely remove the block comment. Source > Add Block Comment adds the start and end of the clock comment to the lines of code, but after running the Formatter (Ctrl + Shift + F), it wraps the lines of code and adds an asterisk to the start of each line. When I try to remove the block comment with Source > Remove Block Comment, the start and end of the block comment is removed, but the asterisks at the beginning of each line is not removed.

How do I prevent Eclipse from adding these asterisks, or remove the asterisks when it removes the start and end of the block comment?

**Example:**

Code like this:

```
    String abc="abc";
    String def="def";
    System.out.println(abc+def);
    System.exit(0);
```

Becomes like this after adding block comments:

```
/*  String abc="abc";
    String def="def";
    System.out.println(abc+def);
*/  System.exit(0);
```

Which becomes like this after applying formatting:

```
    /*
     * String abc="abc"; String def="def"; System.out.println(abc+def);
     */System.exit(0);
```

Which ends up like this after using the Remove Block Comment function:

```
    * String abc="abc"; String def="def"; System.out.println(abc+def);
    System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This may be a little late in the game, but I fixed this by disabling block comment formatting.

```
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> Comments
```

Then uncheck *Enable block comment formatting*.

Comment: Same thing for line comments

Comment: Sadly, this is not a good solution. For one thing, I like the fact that it formats the block comments other than these `*`s, especially when I'm working with other people who have their max line width different from mine. I can just format and is adjusts to my line widths. For another, this does not stop Eclipse form inserting `*`s when you add a new line (hit `Enter`) in the block comment.

Answer (score 16):

One other alternative solution is use of *Block Selection Mode* in eclipse, which is quite fast enough and still keeps your *other* comments formatted. You *just* have to press few keys to remove comments.

In windows you can toggle *Block Selection Mode* by <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. Checkout the screenshot for more.

Steps to follow,

- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to toggle *Block Selection Mode*
- Select vertical section of comment
- Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> again to disable *Block Selection Mode*
- Save the file and you have uncommented the code finally!

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks :)

Comment: Very nice. this is another alternative if we not able to uncheck Enable block comment formatting. Thanks @CoderCroc

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this problem before and my solution is just to use line comments (//) generated by Eclipse instead of block comments. Select code, and then hit Ctrl-/ or Ctrl-7 to toggle // for every line selected. After formatting, those lines will get indented and formatted like text, but if you remove the comments (Ctrl-/ or Ctrl-7) and reformat, everything works fine.

Comment: I suppose that is the only way. It surprises me that Eclipse is not smart enough to tell the difference, though. If no one else has a better solution, I will mark your's as the answer.

Comment: I don't really like this solution either because of all the issues with it when you work with others who format with different line widths. If you make a bunch of line comments, then someone else formats them with a shorter line width, it will make a bunch of short lines that you can't format into a nice block. It's even worse when their line width is something like 2/3 of yours and you get alternating medium- and short-length lines. With block comments, you can format and it adjust to your line width instantly, so I don't want to just stop using block comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ctrl + \ (Back Slash) to remove /* --- --- --- */

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps solve your problem, but I found this very much helpful in my case. Consider this text -

```
String abc="abc";
String def="def";
System.out.println(abc+def);
System.exit(0);
```

After applying a block comment using CTRL + SHIFT + F.

```
/*  String abc="abc";
String def="def";
System.out.println(abc+def);
*/System.exit(0);
```

Just add `-` after `/*` to exclude this block from formatting -

```
/*-  String abc="abc";
String def="def";
System.out.println(abc+def);
*/System.exit(0);
```

Now *Check* Again!!!