# Uncomment multiline code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Yes, this could be duplicate of [Eclipse comment/uncomment shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534748/eclipse-comment-uncomment-shortcut) But, answers given their are not working for my case.

I have formatted java code and When I select and use `ctrl + shift + /` it looks like

```
/*
 * if (isKilled) { Log.i("TAG", "Killed"); }
 */
```

But when I use `ctrl + shift + /` for above selected code, eclipse is not un-commenting my code.

I tried `ctrl + shift + \`, `ctrl + shift + /` and `ctrl + \`.  Nothing worked. I always manually remove *s even if commented code is very big.

How to do this? I also want *s to be removed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse comment/uncomment shortcut?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534748/eclipse-comment-uncomment-shortcut)

Comment: Afaik there is a tendency to move away from `/**/` comments in favor of `//` ones. The `//` comments are easily toggled for multiple lines by `Ctrl + Shift + C`. I guess that this simplicity of IDE support is the reason why many developers prefer `//` over `/**/`.

Comment: Yes `//` could be easy. But is their a way for `/***/` ?

Comment: As of date in 2017 there is no solution for this !

Comment: This is so far  the best solution I found
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34553134/1053496.

Answer (score 10):

Try using  **Ctr+Shift+C**
This should work

Comment: Check your key map. go to tools ->options
then select key map tab. type "comment" in the search bar

Comment: It says toggle comment - java source code. I have tried but not working for *ed multiline code

Comment: Does not work with multiline code when comments have different level (//  //// etc.)

Answer (score 8):

For me `Remove Block Comment` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>) works but only if there is code on the first line of the comment, so your example does not work but:

```
/* if (isKilled) { Log.i("TAG", "Killed"); }
 */
```

does work.

Comment: True, But I am looking for multiline

Comment: This **is** multiline, you have to have code on the first line of the comment.

Comment: I tried with code on first line. Its removing `/*` and `*/` but not removing *s from second line

Comment: Yes, it only works with comments exactly as inserted by `Add Block Comment` - which does not add * on intermediate lines.

Comment: if we format the code which is commented using `/* */`, eclipse editor adds * for intermediate lines too.

Comment: This is the simple answer to this I've been looking for for years - nice one

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse,
To add and remove single line comments,

CNTRL+SHIFT+C

Example:

```
// if(i==1){
// ...
// }
```

To add and remove multi line comments,

CNTRL+SHIFT+/ --> add
CNTRL+SHIFT+\ --> remove

Example:

```
/* if(i==1){
   ...
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

One partial solution to this is to disable block comment formatting.

If you do that, Eclipse will not add * for intermediate lines in multiline block comments when you format the code. And so you will be able to remove such block comments with `Ctrl+Shift+\` or just by removing `/*` and `*/`

In Eclipse for PHP (Windows), in the main menu *Window->Preferences->PHP->CodeStyle->Formatter->Edit->Comments*
Uncheck "Enable block comment formatting"

In other versions of Eclipse this option also exists but under a different path.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a case when ***save actions*** is enabled in eclipse. When you put block comments using "Crtl + Shift + /" or by typing yourself as:

```
/*
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
*/
```

and save it, the editor formats it to

```
 /*
 * line 1
 * line 2
 * line 3
 */
```

* are added on each intermediate lines. This results  **"Crtl + Shift + \"** to fail to remove those **"*"** before the lines.

**The solution is:**

**1- Use "Crtl + Shift + C" to comment and uncomment (toggle). Preferable one.**

2- If you don't want to use "Crtl + Shift + C". This is a hack actually. When you save, the editor formats the code like:

```
 /*
  * line 1
  * line 2
  * line 3
  */
```

You intermediately undo (Crtl + Z) it. The editor will put it back to earlier stage but code is saved like:

```
/*
 line 1
 line 2
 line 3
*/
```

Now you can use "Crtl + Shift + \" to uncomment when needed. The * won't trouble you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am having this problem since ever. Always had in mind that **Ctrl + Shift + C** would away be the right way to comment but it never "uncomment".

Instead just change for to use **Ctrl + /** (for groups also) , or **Ctrl + Shift + /** for /**/ if you prefer.

It never fails, do not stress yourself again.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be as easy. But still it works!
I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to get the Find and Replace window, check the Regular expressions check box and use this regex `^(\s*)/?\*/?(.*)$` and `\1\2` in the replace part and click "Replace All". 
If you want to uncomment only one commented code part, you can select that area and use the radio button "Selected lines" in the scope part.

Regex break up
    
    `^ #denotes start of the line. To avoid matching * in other part of the code.
    ( #first group. To preserve the indentation 
      \s* #selects the tab/space. The indentation
    ) #first group is closed
    /? matches the forward slash in the first line of comment
    \* matches the star(Asterik) in the comments. backward slash is used as a delimiter
    /? matches the forward slash in the last line of comment
    ( #second group. To preserve the indentation 
      .* # the actual code to be uncommented
    ) #second group is closed
    $ # till the end of the line`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the lines of code u wanna comment/uncomment.
2. Then hit "Ctrl + / " to comment/uncomment.

Answer (score -1):

Just replace * with whitespace and remove extra slashes.